# Ruby: counting digits in a float number

Tags: ruby, string, floating-point, digits

Is there any worthy Ruby method to count the number of digits in a float? Also, how do I specify the precise when to_s float numbers?

Comment: Keep in mind that the full number of digits in a float's decimal representation is not necessarily a useful number to have. For example, 0.1 is cannot be precisely represented in binary, so you might not be particularly happy to discover that 0.1 has 18 digits without rounding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Number of digits

12345.23.to_s.split("").size -1 #=> 7

# The precious part

("." + 12345.23.to_s.split(".")[1]).to_f #=> .023

# I would rather used 
# 12345.23 - 12345.23.to_i 
# but this gives 0.22999999999563
```

Comment: Your solution to count digits doesn't take into account the `'-'` on negative numbers.  Also, what's your reasoning for doing `to_s.split("").size` instead of just doing `to_s.size`?

Answer (score 2):

to specify precision of a float in Ruby. you can use the round method.

```
number.round(2)
```

2 is the precision.

```
53.819.round(2) -> 53.82
```

Comment: like rails number_with_precision(precision: 3) just `"%.3f" % 53.82 => "53.820"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check out the [number_with_precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001687) helper.

```
number_with_precision(13, :precision => 5) # => 13.00000
```

Comment: I'm looking for the Ruby solution, not Rails